# Web API Attribute routing in Sitecore 8.1 not working

Tags: c#, sitecore, asp.net-web-api-routing, sitecore8.1

As Atrribute routing does not work in sitecore 8.1 out of the box, I am following https://github.com/Krusen/Sitecore.WebApi
And got the uget package for `Krusen.Sitecore.WebApi.Custom`.

This is my `ConfigureWebApi` class

```
public class ConfigureWebApi
{
    public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {

        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config => config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "myApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            ));
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config => config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes());
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(ReplaceControllerSelector);
    }

    private static void ReplaceControllerSelector(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Services.Replace(typeof (IHttpControllerSelector),
            new CustomHttpControllerSelector(config, new NamespaceQualifiedUniqueNameGenerator()));
    }
}
```

And this is my controller

```
[RoutePrefix("windows")]
public class WmsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("hi")]
    public IHttpActionResult Hello()
    {
        return Ok("Welcome to my Api.");
    }

}
```

When I call this:

```
http://my.api.local/api/wms/hello
```

works.
But when I call

```
http://my.api.local/api/windows/hi
```

does not work. It says 404.

Am I missing something !!

Comment: According to your configuration, shouldn't you call `http://my.api.local/windows/hi`? (without `/api`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second call is not working because Attribute routing must be configured before Convention-based routes to avoid route conflicts.

```cs
public void Process(PipelineArgs args) {
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config => {
        // Map Attribute Routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Map Convention-based Routes
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "myApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // Replace IHttpControllerSelector with our custom implementation
        ReplaceControllerSelector(config);
    });
}
```

Which I also believe is how it was shown in the documentation in the linked repo

Secondly based on the `RoutePrefix("window")` and `Route("hi")` in the `ApiController` the mapped attribute route would be mapped as

```
http://my.api.local/windows/hi
```

To get `http://my.api.local/api/windows/hi` to map to the desired action you would need to update the route prefix as already explained in one of the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "api/" into your controller attribute routing

```
[RoutePrefix("api/windows")]
public class WmsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("hi")]
    public IHttpActionResult Hello()
    {
        return Ok("Welcome to my Api.");
    }

}
```